# Synchronizing XML loading in Action Script 2.0

Tags: xml, actionscript, actionscript-2

I would like to load an XML file into flash. There is the simple code which is familiar to most of user.

```
var myXML=new XML();
myXML.ignoreWhite=true;
myXML.onLoad()=function(success){
    if(success){
        functions_to_process_xml();
    }else{
        trace("not loaded");
    }
}
myXML.load("myxml.xml");
```

Everything looks good till here. But I have a synchronization problem. I just want my swf to start, to load the xml file, and after the myXML.onLoad() finishes, let the other actions happens. I just cannot synchronize my functions start just after the .onLoad() method finishes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the other actions to be executed after you have successfully loaded and parsed the XML data, I think you're on the right track with what you have. Assuming your XML processing routine is synchronous (most likely), all you need to do is initialise the other actions after you have called the XML parsing methods.

I might go for something like this:

```
var myXML=new XML();
myXML.ignoreWhite=true;
myXML.onLoad()=function(success){
    if(success){
        xmlLoadedHandler();
    }else{
        trace("not loaded");
    }
}
myXML.load("myxml.xml");


function xmlLoadedHandler() {
    parseXML(); // most likely a synchronous process
    initOtherActions(); // XML has been loaded and parsed
}
```

If possible you should consider [updating to ActionScript 3.0](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/first_as3_application.html).